# Can ble record values be corrupted in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to discover my ble devices and when I scan I do find my device but my record values are inconsistent. It is supposed to advertise a value and when I read the record sometimes it shows garbage value(not that I need and is not readable) while sometimes it is right. So doe sit depend on what time we do the scan and how it broadcasts? Or is there something else that I am missing because the same device advertises correctly on ios.

EDIT: 
// Device scan callback. Record is scan record and here I get in my case 25 bytes.

```
 private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi,
            final byte[] scanRecord) {
        }
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "record values"? The Bluetooth address or a characteristic value?

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: Doesn't `scanRecord` contain all found devices? You may pick up other devices as they come in and out of range. `scanRecord` is not always the same.

Comment: No I am not getting the same. I am printing the data and I get a set of array and next time I discover again and it is different.

Comment: That's what is my curiosity is who could be corrupting it. Is it the adapter that is not reading it well or is it the device that is sending the wrong data.

Comment: its the same device and it advertises the same number

Comment: "No I am not getting the same. I am printing the data and I get a set of array and next time I discover again and it is different." That is what I am saying; `scanRecord` will be different depending on the advertisements it picks up. The device you are trying to find may be on an advertising schedule and so `scanRecord` might contain it sometimes but not every time. Have you tried scanning and waiting and then scanning again?